# How to fix ugly fonts in Firefox 18?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I just installed Firefox 18 and I was horrified to see Gmail's font rendering (the problem occurs also in Iceweasel 18 from Debian). The problem does not occur in Chromium.

See here:

[image]

Now, I tried a couple of things:

1. I removed Arial from my computer.
2. I followed [a hint in the SUSE forums](http://forums.opensuse.org/archives/sf-archives/archives-software/340275-ugly-fonts-gmail-under-firefox.html) (the last one customising the Chrome CSS files).

I still don't get it to work. Does someone know how to change it? What if I don't want to use Arial at all in Gmail? Can I do something about it?

Why does Firefox misbehave?

### Edit:

I found the solution to  problem how to change the font in GMail, a [Greasemonkey script for GMAIL](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/104846).
Unfortunatly, the font are still blury. It seems like a bug in FF for Linux.

Comment: +1. lol for use of 'horrified' in the context of the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is a known issue:

In `about:config`, edit keys in the following way:

```
Set layers.acceleration.force-enabled to true
Set layers.acceleration.disabled to false
```

After doing that, restart Firefox and you’re ready to go.

Credit to [Original solution from here](http://open.knome.fi/2013/02/05/fuzzy-fonts-in-firefox-18-no-more/http://open.knome.fi/2013/02/05/fuzzy-fonts-in-firefox-18-no-more/).

Answer (score 2):

- Chrome: [Font Changer with Google Web Fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer-with-google/jgjhhoglgjdklldfgoffdiaceffijeke)
- Firefox: [Theme Font & Size Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/theme-font-size-changer/?src=search)

I use both.

Comment: it is not what I asked. I asked how to I change the font of GMail, not the FF or Chromes.